# bash scripts and ant

Tags: java, bash, shell, ant

I have a build file that calls a script like this:

```
<exec executable="/bin/bash" failonerror="true">
         <arg value="wrapper_generatedConfig.sh"/>
</exec>
```

The wrapper_generatedConfig.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAIN_PATH=/opt/app/Gateway/gateway-1.6
LIB_PATH=$MAIN_PATH/lib
XML_LIB_PATH=$MAIN_PATH/lib/xml
PROD_LIB_PATH=$MAIN_PATH/prod_lib
ABN_LIB_PATH=$MAIN_PATH/abn_lib
ABN_LIB_EXT_PATH=$MAIN_PATH/abn_lib/ext

WS_LIB_PATH=$MAIN_PATH/web/CPMessageCenterWebSrvc/WEB-INF/lib

WRAPPER_CONFIG_FILENAME=$MAIN_PATH/config/wrapper.conf
WRAPPER_CONFIG_INITIAL=$MAIN_PATH/config/initialWrapper.conf

CP=""

declare -i count=1

WRAPPER=wrapper.java.classpath.
rm $WRAPPER_CONFIG_FILENAME

cp $WRAPPER_CONFIG_INITIAL $WRAPPER_CONFIG_FILENAME

#call the other script first before calling its function inside for loops.
. wrapper_cpappend.sh

for a in $LIB_PATH/*.jar
      do append $LIB_PATH/$a
done

for a in $XML_LIB_PATH/*.jar
        do append $XML_LIB_PATH/$a
done

for a in $PROD_LIB_PATH/*.jar
        do append $PROD_LIB_PATH/$a
done

for a in $ABN_LIB_EXT_PATH/*.jar
        do append $ABN_LIB_EXT_PATH/$a
done

for a in $ABN_LIB_PATH/*.jar
        do append $ABN_LIB_PATH/$a
done

append $WS_LIB_PATH/axis.jar
append $WS_LIB_PATH/saaj.jar
append $WS_LIB_PATH/wsdl4j.jar
append $WS_LIB_PATH/commons-discovery.jar
append $WS_LIB_PATH/commons-logging.jar
append $WS_LIB_PATH/axis-ant.jar


# Clean up the variables defined.
 CP=""

echo ------------------------------------------------
if [ -f "$WRAPPER_CONFIG_FILENAME" ];
then
        echo $WRAPPER_CONFIG_FILENAME has been created.
else
        echo Error in creating $WRAPPER_CONFIG_FILENAME!
fi
echo ------------------------------------------------

sleep 2
```

Which calls wrapper_cpappend.sh.
The wrapper_cpappend.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $count
if [ $1="" ]; then
  exit
fi

append()
{
    count=$count+1
    echo wateves
    CP=$WRAPPER$count=$1
    echo $CP >> $WRAPPER_CONFIG_FILENAME
}
```

When run the build file using "ant -buildfile deploy.xml" I get build successful message but the second script with append() function does not get run properly. It does not append the jar files to wrapper.conf file

I got this working at 2 days ago as sudo logged in as root user. But something happened when i was messing with count variable and it stopped working. if i put log entry inside the append script, it says "append needs 1 arg" even though i am sending the argument.
I am starting to think its not the script and its something to do it ant..

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this if statement was problematic.

```
if [ $1="" ]; then
  exit
fi
```

This always return true and hence the script was exiting each time never moving forward.
So changed it to this proper check:

```
if [ -z $1 ];
 exit
fi
```

And all is well now!! :)